# Python printing weird characters

Tags: python

I'm running Windows 11, with the output in Windows Terminal

```
from gnewsclient import gnewsclient
import requests

print("requesting google news...") 
news_list = gnewsclient.NewsClient('english', 'entertainment', 'US', 10).get_news()
 
item = news_list[0]
print("extracting text from web page...")

title = item['title'].rpartition(' - ')[0]

print(title)
print(item['link'])
```

output:

```
requesting google news...
extracting text from web page...
ภาวะตลาดหุ้นไทย: ดิ่ง 28.82 จุด ตามตลาดหุ้นโลกผวาเงินเฟ้อสหรัฐพุ่ง-กังวล MSCI - อาร์วายที9
https://news.google.com/__i/rss/rd/articles/CBMiI2h0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnJ5dDkuY29tL3MvaXEwNS8zMzIxNzcx0gEA?oc=5
```

Does anyone know how to correct this text?

Comment: Okay, and? What is your **question**? Did you try looking at the web page in a browser? What I see that way looks similar to your output, so I can't see how there is any problem. Are you familiar with Thai language?

Comment: You're not doing anything with `soup`.

Comment: "Does anyone know how to correct this text?" What do you think is wrong with the text? What do you expect to see instead? Why?

Comment: I didn't realize it was actually Thai, I thought it was some encoding issue lol. My config was set to US.

Comment: Standard "are the lights on" debugging steps here: 1. Look at the page in a web browser. 2. copy and paste the text to a machine-translation service, asking it to auto-detect the language.

Comment: But now as I access other pages from the news_list, they all appear to be Thai...

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is the order of the parameters.  You should read the code.    It wants location, then language, then topic.  So, you're not telling it to send English.  This is why the documentation suggests using named parameters.

```
news_list = gnewsclient.NewsClient(language='english', topic='entertainment', location='US', max_results=10).get_news()
```